# How to check if the units are the same with class templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following program in which two templated structs called Measure are passed to another templated struct called Measure_add. The Measure struct has two attributes.
A value and a unit.

**Problem statement:**

I managed to add the values to, but the unit's still don't work. I need to work with struct template spezialization. I want to first check if the units are the same.

If the units are both in meter (m), then the class Unit can be set to m.

If the units are not the same, I need to convert the highest unit to the lower unit. So imagine that Measure1 has Unit km and Measure2 has Unit m, then I need to convert the Measure1 value to meters.

I note that there are at least two different tasks if case of 2 different units:

- determining which unit is the smallest
- converting the value of Measure1 and do the addition again.

**What do I need in order to proceed?:**

How do I do this without if statements? Since if statements are not allowed withing structs?

Could someone please show me how to do this for a case when Measure1 is km and Measure2 is m? I think I could reproduce that for other cases

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Unit { km, m, cm };

template<int v, Unit u>
struct Measure
{
    static const int value = v;
    static const Unit unit = u;
};

template< typename  a, typename b>
struct Measure_add
{
    static const Unit unit = a::unit;
    static const int value = a::value + b ::value;
};


int main()
{
    
    std::cout << Measure_add< Measure<4, Unit::m>, Measure<4, Unit::km> >::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend reading about [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Comment: You need to define the ratio between every unit in some way. Take a look at [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio).

Comment: A lot of support for compile-time features are located in [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits). It defines traits like `std::conditional` which can act as an `if` in a `class` definition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Francois already mentioned all you need in comments. [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and  [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) can be of great use here.

First I suggest you to sort the units in increasing order:

```
enum class Unit { cm, m, km };
```

Then you can use a helper to find between two `Measure`s the one with the smaller unit and the one with the larger unit:

```
template <typename A,typename B>
struct minmax_unit {
    using smaller = typename std::conditional<A::unit < B::unit,A,B>::type;
    using larger = typename std::conditional<A::unit < B::unit,B,A>::type;
};
```

You can use `std::ratio` to define ratios between your `Unit`s:

```
template <Unit, Unit> struct UnitRatio;
template <> struct UnitRatio<Unit::m,Unit::km> : std::ratio<1000,1> {};
template <> struct UnitRatio<Unit::cm,Unit::m> : std::ratio<100,1> {};
template <> struct UnitRatio<Unit::cm,Unit::km> : std::ratio<100000,1> {};
```

Note that not necessarily you need `UnitRatio< bigger unit , smaller unit >`. But you will need `UnitRatio< x,x>` which I omitted here.

You can add a helper that calls the actual template with first parameter always being the one with smaller unit and use the above ratios:

```
template< typename  a, typename b>
struct Measure_add_impl
{
    static const Unit unit = a::unit;
    static const int value = a::value * UnitRatio<a::unit,b::unit>::den
                           + b::value * UnitRatio<a::unit,b::unit>::num;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Measure_add : Measure_add_impl<
                        typename minmax_unit<A,B>::smaller,
                        typename minmax_unit<A,B>::larger> {};
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ratio>

enum class Unit { cm, m, km };

template<int v, Unit u>
struct Measure
{
    static const int value = v;
    static const Unit unit = u;
};

template <typename A,typename B>
struct minmax_unit {
    using smaller = typename std::conditional<A::unit < B::unit,A,B>::type;
    using larger = typename std::conditional<A::unit < B::unit,B,A>::type;
};

template <Unit, Unit> struct UnitRatio;
template <> struct UnitRatio<Unit::m,Unit::km> : std::ratio<1000,1> {};
template <> struct UnitRatio<Unit::cm,Unit::m> : std::ratio<100,1> {};
template <> struct UnitRatio<Unit::cm,Unit::km> : std::ratio<100000,1> {};

template< typename  a, typename b>
struct Measure_add_impl
{
    static const Unit unit = a::unit;
    static const int value = a::value * UnitRatio<a::unit,b::unit>::den
                           + b::value * UnitRatio<a::unit,b::unit>::num;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Measure_add : Measure_add_impl<
                        typename minmax_unit<A,B>::smaller,
                        typename minmax_unit<A,B>::larger> {};

int main()
{    
    std::cout << Measure_add< Measure<8, Unit::m>, Measure<4, Unit::km> >::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
4008
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/99bz84)

---

> How to check if the units are the same with class templates?

As `Unit` is an enum, it is rather straightforward to see if two units are equal:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct has_same_unit {
    static const bool value = A::unit == B::unit;
};

int main()
{    
    std::cout << has_same_unit< Measure<8, Unit::m>, Measure<4, Unit::km> >::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a set of functions to do unit conversions that exist outside the template. For instance:

```
static Unit MultiplyUnitConversion(Unit u1, Unit u2);
static Unit DivideUnitConversion(Unit dividend, divisor u2);
```

You'll also need some error handling method, two ideas are throwing an exception or create a new Unit enum value to indicate an invalid unit.

I recognize this isn't a full answer. Since if I were writing it I'd prefer that the functions were just automatically made available to the template without having to include a separate module or library and also without a "that function already exists" error. I believe this is possible, but I don't remember how.